# android retrieve item clicked original table id

Tags: android

I have a listview populated with items retrieved from database (mysql). all is working fine and data is showing as required. Now is the time for the last step: when an item on the table is clicked, it should load more details on that item in next page. This is simple enough I believe. If I can get the id of the element based on database table, then I can query on next screen and load data easily.

The problem is how can I get the id of the item as it is on the mysql table? below is my adapter and list code:

this is the adapterview method that does most of the work:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(arg1==null)
            arg1 = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.simplerow ,arg2, false);

        TextView name = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.nameTxtView);
        TextView rate = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.rateTxtView);
        //name.setText(discountObjectArray[arg0].name + "---> " + discountObjectArray[arg0].location + "---> " +discountObjectArray[arg0].rate);
        String tempName = discountObjectArray[arg0].name;


        tempName = ellipsize(tempName, 6);
        name.setText(tempName);
        rate.setText(discountObjectArray[arg0].rate);
        return arg1;
    }
    public static String ellipsize(String input, int maxLength) {
          if (input == null || input.length() <= maxLength) {
            return input;
          }
          return input.substring(0, maxLength-1) + "...";
        }

}
```

and this is the list code displaying a simple toast:

discountListingListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {


                RelativeLayout tempParent = (RelativeLayout) view;
                TextView t = (TextView) tempParent.findViewById(R.id.nameTxtView);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), t.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

I am pretty new to android and appreciate your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the database id as an attribute of discountObjectArray element. Then in your adapter override this method:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return discountObjectArray[position].id;
}
```

Now the database id will be available as an "id" argument of onItemClick method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use to ArrayList or List on your ArrayAdapter.. This;

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            String Name = discountObjectArray[position].name;                
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```